# Label the nodes in a tree with their depth as a linear or quadratic problem.

Tags: graph-theory, linear-programming, trees, constraints, quadratic-programming

I have a tree made by selecting a few edges out of a graph, in a quadratic programming problem (actually conic).

I would like to assign a variable representing the distance from the root to each node for the given selection of edges.

This has to be done inside the programming problem to minimise an objective, so it must be some set of constraints.

My idea for now is something like this:

Let $a_{ij}$ represent the selection of the link between i and j for the tree as a binary variable, and $d_i$ be the depth of the node i.

$a_{ij}*(d_j-d_i)=1$ would imply that if I select the link ij then the depth of j is 1 more than the depth of i.

The problem is that the graph is undirected, so I don't know if i was actually the node closer to the root, and hence it could be that the depth of i is more than the depth of j.

$a_{ij}*(d_j-d_i)^2=1$
Is no longer quadratic and it also doesn't solve the problem.

What can I do? I was also thinking about some flux based formulation, but no luck for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If inequality constraints are allowed, we can “encode” that if the link $ij$ is selected then depths $d_i$ and $d_j$ differs by $1$ by the following inequalities:

$(d_i-d_j)^2\ge a_{ij}$,

$a_{ij}(d_i-d_j)\le 1$,

$a_{ij}(d_j-d_i)\le 1$.

Indeed, if $a_{ij}=0$ then all inequalities hold for arbitrary $d_i$ and $d_j$. But if $a_{ij}=1$ then the first inequality implies $|d_i-d_j|\ge 1$, whereas the other inequalities imply $|d_i-d_j|\le 1$, so $|d_i-d_j|=1$.

Comment: this is a nice idea, but I fear it will not work. let's say that i is the root (depth 0) and j has depth 1 since aij=1. with this set of constraints dj could be either 1 or -1, since it only implies that the difference between the depths is 1. am I wrong? thanks for the answer

Comment: I just got this idea: using your constraints I could add to my objective function the maximization of the sum of the di. if I pick a really low value for its weight in the multi objective I think it implies that (if I set the root as d=0) the depth will be increasing after each hop (but it also implies the desire to maximise the overall depth of the three, hence the very low weight). what do you think about this approach? it's not really elegant, but if it's the only way....

Comment: @user3149593 I’ll think, how we can overcome this obstacle. Indeed, the constraints $|d_i-d_j|=1$ are not sufficient to determine all $d_i$’s. We can also add the constraints that all $d_i$’s are non-negative. Also, because any node of a tree can be selected as its root, I have a question, how we determine the root of the tree? It is some fixed node $i_0$?

Comment: the root is something I select out of the nodes before running the optimization and set as a constraint for the problem. basically I pick a root and tell my program ''find me a tree with this root compliant with the other constraints''. For now thanks again!

Comment: @user3149593 OK, given the fixed root, the constraints $d_i\ge 0$, and the constraints encoding $|d_i-d_j|=1$ provided $a_{ij}=1$, we can use a new trick. If both $a_{lj}=1$ and $a_{lk}=1$ and $j\ne k$ then $2d_l\le d_j+d_k$. Induction by depth of a node shows that when we add all such conditions we ensure all $d_i$’s to have the correct values. We can “encode” the trick condition by the constraint  $(8n-4d_l)\ge (a_{lj}+a_{lk})(4n-d_j-d_k)$, where $n$ is the number of nodes (which is a priori bigger than each of $d_i$’s).

Comment: Thank you a lot @Alex Ravsky, I still need to figure out the meaning of this constraints exactly, but I get the general idea. I feel like this would work with multiple roots too (given a radiality constraints), all I would need to do is set the root(s) depth at zero and it should hold, right? I will accept your answer when I figure out the ''encode'' constraint. Thanks again.

Comment: I think it should be $2d_l<d_j+d_k$, am I wrong? I imagine $d_l=2$, the two children j and k with depth $d_j=1$ and $d_k=3$. this configuration is wrong ( a child has a lower depth than its parent) yet it satisfies the constraint at equality. It also seems that we oriented the graph ($a_il+a_li<=1) this is not a problem, but I want to be sure. I'm more concerned about extending this result to non binary trees, but seems doable.

Comment: starting from your reasoning I think I found a decent constraint for a non binary tree. I'd write $(\sum_j a_{lj}) d_l <  \sum_j a_{lj}d_j$. I directed the graph in the means of the previous comment. What do you think? thanks again and sorry for the multiple comments, but the flow of ideas can't be stopped.

Comment: @user3149593 1. Present constraints do not work for multiple roots. For instance, for a five vertex path with two endpoints as the roots we have the sequence  $(0,1,2,1,0)$ of degrees along the path, which is forbidden by present constraints.

Comment: 2. It should be $2d_l\le d_j+d_k$. The inequality $2d_l<d_j+d_k$ doesn’t hold even for a path rooted at the start point, which has the sequence  $(0,1,2,3,\dots)$ of degrees along the path. I recall that the constraint $2d_l\le d_j+d_k$ should be satisfied for *all* triples $(j,l,k)$ of mutally distinct numbers such that both $a_{lj}=1$ and $a_{lk}=1$ are  (simulataneously) possible.

Comment: 3. I recall that “Induction by depth of a node shows that when we add all such conditions we ensure all $d_i$’s to have the correct values”. In particular, at each level $d\ge 1$ of depth we prove that $d_l=d$ for each node $l$ of depth $d$. Then, in particular, no child $k$ of such $d_l$ can have degree $d_k=d_l-1$, because $d_j=d_l-1$ for a parent $j$ of the node $l$, which leads to  the contradiction with the inequality $2d_l\le d_j+d_k$.

Comment: 4. I consider the graph as undirected, that is $a_{il}=a_{li}$ for each $i$ and $l$.

Comment: 5. The present constraints already should work for all trees, not only binary.

Comment: 6. The proposition of the inequality $(\sum_j a_{lj})d_l<\sum_j a_{lj}d_j$ is based on wrong assumptions, and even in a corrected form  $(\sum_j a_{lj})d_l\le \sum_j a_{lj}d_j$ when the degree of the node $l$ is at least $4$ it does not forbid some its children to have a depth less than the degree of the node $l$.

Comment: you were really clear, now I understood how things work. thanks! my only concern is that $a_ij(d_i−d_j)≤1$ and the other link won't work in gurobi or cplex (I get the error ''Q is not positive definite'') so I'll need to look for another solver. Thanks again for all your help!